# Safe navigation operator (lonely operator) not working for hash

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use the safe navigation operator `&` to optionally call the `[]` method on a variable which may be a hash or `nil`. As far as I know, that's what safe navigation operators are for.

```
my_hash = nil
puts "hello, #{ my_hash&[:test] }"
my_hash = { test: "world" }
puts "hello, #{ my_hash&[:test] }"
```

I expect this to output:

```
hello, false
hello, world
```

But but it does not work with hashes; instead, I get:

```
hello, false
undefined method `&` for `{:test=>"world"}:Hash` (NoMethodError)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "a hash which may or may not be `nil`"---This is self contradiction. A hash is not `nil`.

Comment: Among other things, nil#to_s doesn't do what you think: `"#{nil}" #=> ""` rather than `"false"`.

Comment: @CodeGnome actually `nil#to_s` does exactly what I think. What tripped me up is that `nil&[:test] #=> false` for some reason. If you can explain that part to me, I'd be super grateful.

Comment: To answer my own question, `nil & [:test]` is a bitwise operation between `nil `and an array. `nil & obj` always returns `false`, a choice which I don't entirely understand.

Comment: It is actually not a bitwise operation. It just returns `nil` by design. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/NilClass.html#method-i-26

Comment: @eiko `nil & [:test]` is parsed as `nil.& [:test]` which always returns false. However, `[:test] & nil` raises TypeError. Sometimes it's useful to understand how the Ruby parser is interpreting the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because this

```
my_hash[:test]
```

is syntactic sugar for this one

```
my_hash.[](:test)
```

so this should work

```
my_hash&.[](:test)
```

but it's not pretty, I know.

Comment: What's the point? `hash.[] :test #=> nil` anyway, so there's no need for safe navigation because there's nothing to rescue.

Comment: @CodeGnome I think you misunderstood the question. your `hash` can be nil. That's the point

Comment: I agree. CodeGnome completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: No, a Hash can be empty, but it can't be nil. This answer *seems* right because you're assuming you have an empty Hash, but it's just silently swallowing a NoMethodError on nil based on the OP's example code.

Comment: When I say `hash` I'm referring to a variable, not an hash object. Anyway, this `nil&.[](:test)` evaluates to `nil`, no `NoMethodError`

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to use `&` to optionally call the `[]` method on a hash which may or may not be `nil`.

In order to do that, you need to directly invoke the `[]` *method*. `hash[:key]` is actually calling the `:[]` method on the hash:

```
# This will not work:
my_hash&[:test]

# This will:
my_hash&.[](:test)
```

This is clearly not the prettiest solution, though... You may instead want to use a guard clause in the method (`return if my_hash.nil?`), or do something like this:

```
my_hash.to_h[:test]
```

Comment: Upvoted because using `to_h` on `nil` is a clever thing I hadn't considered!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that there is no such thing as "the safe navigation operator `&`" as you assume.

What is called the safe navigation operator is `&.`. Nowhere in your code:

```
my_hash&[:test]
```

is there a safe navigation operator `&.`.

Answer (score -3):

### TL;DR

You've got logic and syntax errors in your program including:

- Treating nil (an instance of NilClass) like an empty Hash.
- Misunderstanding what's being returned by interpolation of nil (`""`).
- Syntax errors in your use of the safe navigation operator (`&.`).

In the sections below, I address your logic errors and offer some suggestions for using native Hash methods that accomplish the results your looking for without silently swallowing errors that would have brought more attention to the problematic parts of the code.

The goal of this answer isn't just to point out errors, but to also demonstrate how to accomplish what you're trying to do successfully. Your mileage may vary.

### Fixing Your Logic Errors

There's are a couple of key logic error in your original question. If you want to return "false" for interpolation if a Hash value doesn't exist, use #fetch. For example:

```
hash = {}
hash.fetch :test, false
#=> false
```

However, there's an important caveat. **Hash#fetch will raise a NoMethodError if called on nil, because nil doesn't respond to fetch:**

```
nil.respond_to? :fetch
#=> false
```

*This* is the problem safe navigation is designed to handle: a missing method. It therefore makes sense to use safe navigation if you swallow the exception rather than rescue it or handle it with #method_missing. For example:

```
hash = nil
hash.fetch :test, false
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `fetch' for nil:NilClass

hash&.fetch :test, false
#=> nil
```

However, doing this essentially results in silently swallowing an error in the same way that `hash.fetch :test rescue false` would, so it's generally the wrong thing to do because it hides the fact that there's a logic problem or that you've gotten ahold of an unexpected object like nil rather than an empty hash. However, it would certainly solve your interpolation problem:

```
hash = nil
"#{hash.fetch :test rescue false}"
#=> "false"
```

For your posted code, I stress that you probably want to use sensible Hash methods that *don't* silently swallow exceptions, but your real-world mileage may certainly vary.

### Safe Navigator Not Needed; Use Existing Hash Methods

You appear to have at least four other related problems in your original question:

1. The safe navigation operator is `&.` so it only works with methods using dotted notation. `my_hash&[:test]` is not a valid construct for that.
2. The safe navigator handles objects that lack a given method. However, [Hash#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) exists, so even if the parser considered `Hash&.[]` to be a valid construct (which it doesn't), this wouldn't do what you're expecting anyway.
3. You probably want [Hash#fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) or [Hash#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) instead, depending on the expected structure of your hash and the object you want to return.
4. When you use string interpolation on nil, you're implicitly calling #to_s. But `nil.to_s` doesn't do what you think; it returns an empty string, not an instance of FalseClass. For proof, consider that `"#{nil}" #=> ""`.

#### Examples of Relevant Hash Methods

Consider the following examples:

```
hash = {}

hash.fetch :test
#=> KeyError: key not found: :test

hash.fetch :test, nil
#=> nil

hash.values_at :test
#=> [nil]
```

Hash#fetch with a default of nil is probably what you want in most cases, although you can certainly rescue KeyError or `rescue nil` (or even `rescue false`) if you prefer to do that, although a catch-all rescue for truly unexpected exceptions is generally considered a code smell.

Comment: Your mentioning of `Hash&.[]` is wrong, or misleading at best. In fact, `Hash&.[]` is not an invalid construct as you write. (It is equivalent to `{}`). You meant what it is not.

Comment: By mentioning `fetch`, and `values_at` you are completely misunderstanding the OP's intent. OP is not intending to call the default `nil` on a hash. OP wants to call `[]` on a variable that may be `nil` or a hash.

Comment: @sawa You are a philsophunculist. `hash&.[]` raises ArgumentError. Furthermore, since `hash.[] :test #=> nil` anyway, what's the point of using the safe navigator at all? —You're welcome to play FGITW, but you're missing the forest for the trees here, and failing to explain anything but the error in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47018559/1301972) without providing useful guidance to the OP about what to do instead.

Comment: How is `hash&.[]` relevant when you are talking about `Hash&.[]`?

Comment: The question is "What am I doing wrong?" My answer answers that properly.

Comment: I think this answer is an excellent example of trying to explain OPs original mental "mistakes"

Naming them individually and giving examples really helps someone trying to improve as a programmer.

All of these issues are conflated together in the original question making it very hard to answer clearly.

btw: `my_hash = {}; my_hash&.[](:test)`

Is a very confusing looking piece of ruby code.